# Format output of writeJson in Deno

Tags: javascript, json, file, environment-variables, deno

I'm using Deno 1.7 and would like to format the output of the JSON file to look like a normal JSON file that has return lines and indentions/tabs.  Yet this is not what I'm seeing when passing in a JSON style string.

---

Question: What should I change in order to get a file that is not on one line (properly formatting JSON)?

---

NOTE:

For your reference, the following is the latest, updated code, that actually works based on the answer given below.

The structure of the app is:

> - app.ts (entry point)
> - write-json.ts (module that writes package.json)
> - deps.ts
> - .env
> - package.json (this is the output of the application)

The deno command I run is:

> $ deno run --allow-read --allow-env --allow-write app.ts

// app.ts

```
import { config } from './deps.ts';
import { writePackageJsonFile } from './write-json.ts';

config({ export: true, safe: true });

const packageName: string = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_NAME')!;
const content: string = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_CONTENTS')!;
if(!packageName || !content){
  throw new Error("You must provide a valid file name and file content");
}

try {
  const parsedContent: any = JSON.parse(content);
  console.log(parsedContent)
  await writePackageJsonFile(packageName, parsedContent);
} catch (_) {
  throw new Error("The content provided for the file is not a valid JSON object");
}
```

// deps.ts

```
import { config } from 'https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts';
 
export { config };
```

// write-json.ts

```
import { writeJson, writeJsonSync } from 'https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts';

export async function writePackageJsonFile(filename: string, contents: any) {
  await writeJson(filename, contents, { spaces: 2 });
}
```

// .env

```
PACKAGE_NAME="package.json"
PACKAGE_CONTENTS='{"name": "app", "version": "1.0.0", "scripts": { "start": "METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat settings.json) node main.js" } }'
```

Comment: Also, the JSON in the environment variable is invalid. They keys and the values which are strings must be in double-quotes `"`. So change them to `MY_VAR='{"key": "value"}'`. Then parse the JSON first, and then stringify it as - `JSON.stringify(parsedJson, null, 2)`. Ref - [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code

```js
import { config } from 'https://deno.land/x/dotenv/mod.ts';
import { writeJson } from 'https://deno.land/x/jsonfile/mod.ts';

// replace with correct type
type PackageJson = object

config({ export: true, safe: true });

async function writePackageJsonFile(filename: string, contents: PackageJson) {
  await writeJson(filename, contents, { spaces: 2 });
}

const packageName: string = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_NAME')!;
const content: string = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_CONTENTS')!;

const parsedContent: PackageJson = JSON.parse(content);
await writePackageJsonFile(packageName, parsedContent);
```

```
PACKAGE_NAME="package.json"
PACKAGE_CONTENTS='{"name": "app", "version": "1.0.0", "scripts": { "start": "METEOR_SETTINGS=$(cat settings.json) node main.js" } }'
```

The problem was that `writeJson` takes an object as content to be written rather than the string.

So, in the very original question, you need to change the quotes and parse the `packageContents` and pass the parsed content to the `writePackageJsonFile` function.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any library to do this, Deno has the built in function to write and format JSON and it's as simple as the following

```
// Use whatever package you want here to read the .env file

const file_name = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_NAME');
const content = Deno.env.get('PACKAGE_CONTENTS');

if(!file_name || !content){
  throw new Error("You must provide a valid file name and file content");
}

let json_object;
try{
  json_object = JSON.parse(content);
}catch(_){
  throw new Error("The content provided for the file is not a valid JSON object");
}

// Using two spaces to format
await Deno.writeTextFile(
  new URL(file_name, import.meta.url),
  JSON.stringify(json_object, null, 2),
);

// Using tab to format
await Deno.writeTextFile(
  new URL(file_name, import.meta.url),
  JSON.stringify(json_object, null, "\t"),
);
```

You can read more about the Deno builtins in the following link https://doc.deno.land/builtin/stable

And about JSON.stringify here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, but I'd like to have the json object part pulled in from a enviornment variable in a .env file.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  I gave you a upvote, also, like the addition of try/catch and checking if the input from the .env fiiles are valid.

Answer (score 0):

Try `await writePackageJsonFile(packageName, JSON.parse(packageContents));`, and change `contents: string` to `contents: any`, so that it accepts an object (Or recreate the object structure and assign that type).

Comment: Deno allows top level awaits right (doesn't need to be in an async function)?

Comment: Ah, nevermind that then @Aaron, never used Deno before.